# What emails should I create for a web services company?

Tags: web-development, website-design

I am building a software and web services company and want to create different email account to use them in contacting my team, customers "which i do for them websites for example", users of the company website, jobs, ....

I want to know what are emails you recommend to create and the use of each.

*note: I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so if not, please help me where to ask such questions.*

Comment: Don't create different emails just because "others do it", create them if you need them. One of the reasons companies have multiple emails is because the guy handling job applications isn't the same as the guy handling customer support, or they felt overwhelmed and unable to find the stuff they need. Addressing emails regarding critical bugs is more urgent than reading job applications. With different emails, they can conveniently address them in the order they see fit.

Comment: @ Kristian, Yes I understood your point, but for example some create an email account for jobs called career, so I am asking if there is a standard professional email accounts list to choose from.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard, and I don't see a reason why there should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before creating emails that might only frustrate your current customers and the new potential ones, I suggest you to [read this article](http://blog.asmartbear.com/one-email.html).

From my personal experience as a customer I usually find quite frustrating, whenever I need to ask something to a vendor, to be forced to think at what mail address I should send my issue.

In other words, let's say you just bought some web service, if your order wasn't processed by the vendor, but you already paied for it, do you complain to:

- order@vendor.com
- or to payment@vendor.com
- or to invoices@vendor.com
- or to info@vendor.com

**Don't you think it's quite confusing?**

As a customer I would like to complain always to info@vendor.com and the vendor should take care to dispatch my message to the right place, not me!

Answer (score 0):

The email addresses I normally see on the web are:

**sales** for all product/service questions

**info**  Similar to sales but may be used for a non-comercial products/services.

**support** For question or problems relating to your product/service

**accounts** For billing/payment issues e.g. why has my account been disabled or why is my bill $134 when it should only be $50

**admin / webmaster**  To report broken links, spam or other problems with your website that need to be fixed.

But like Kristian Antonsen mentioned you can just have one email and add more as needed.
Or if you want to appear like a larger company then you really are you make each email address an alias which all get redirected back to a single Email address. Then if you expand your company and need to hire new staff for these roles then you just change the email alias to an real email address.